# Android smart-card interface over USB

Tags: android, usb, smartcard

I need to read/write to a smart-card using a smart-card reader attached to an Android phone by USB.
Is this possible with native APIs or do I have to install other libraries?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In java the communication takes place using package `javax.smarcard` which is not available for Android so take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366577/5134647) for getting an idea as to how you can communicate or send/receive APDU (smartcard command).

Using the USB Host API to connect :
:

```
//Allows you to enumerate and communicate with connected USB devices.
UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
//Explicitly asking for permission
final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();

UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("//the device you want to work with");
if (device != null) {
    mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
}
```

And now you will need endpoints, simply send an APDU (smartcard command) over the bulk-out endpoint and expect to receive a response APDU over the bulk-in endpoint.

Code to get endpoints ::

```
UsbEndpoint epOut = null, epIn = null;
UsbInterface usbInterface;

UsbDeviceConnection connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);

    for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
        usbInterface = device.getInterface(i);
        connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true);

        for (int j = 0; j < usbInterface.getEndpointCount(); j++) {
            UsbEndpoint ep = usbInterface.getEndpoint(j);

            if (ep.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
                    // from host to device
                    epOut = ep;

                } else if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                    // from device to host
                    epIn = ep;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To send commands use this :

```
public void write(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbEndpoint epOut, byte[] command) {
result = new StringBuilder();
connection.bulkTransfer(epOut, command, command.length, TIMEOUT);
//For Printing logs you can use result variable
for (byte bb : command) {
    result.append(String.format(" %02X ", bb));
}
}
```

And to read data or send binary read you can use this code:

```
public int read(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbEndpoint epIn) {
result = new StringBuilder();
final byte[] buffer = new byte[epIn.getMaxPacketSize()];
int byteCount = 0;
byteCount = connection.bulkTransfer(epIn, buffer, buffer.length, TIMEOUT);
//For Printing logs you can use result variable
if (byteCount >= 0) {
    for (byte bb : buffer) {
        result.append(String.format(" %02X ", bb));
    }

    //Buffer received was : result.toString()
} else {
    //Something went wrong as count was : " + byteCount
}

return byteCount;
}
```

Now let's take an example of this command like the one here: `62000000000000000000` How you can send this is :

```
write(connection, epOut, "62000000000000000000");
```

Now after you have successfully sent the APDU command, you can read the response using :

```
read(connection, epIn);
```

And receive something like

```
80 18000000 00 00 00 00 00 3BBF11008131FE45455041000000000000000000000000F1
```

Now the response received in the code here will be in the result variable of `read()` method.And likewise you can write your own commands for communicating.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no abstraction layer like `PC/SC` in the native Android system. But you can utilize [Android USB library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) to talk directly to the USB smart card reader.

Comment: Actually I need to attach the card reader to the phone directly through USB, because I won't have a PC or anything else, jsut the Android phone and the card reader.

Comment: And also I need to support phones that do not have NFC

Comment: Wait, so you mean you want to connect a USB smart card reader to an Android phone?

Comment: yes exactly. there is an app that supports this by SC & Droid, but they do not provide the code

Comment: But since the smart card reader devices mainly belongs to the CCID USB class, do I have to implement this protocol over the UBS Library?

Comment: Yes, this would be the case.