# using OmniKey card reader with Android Box - reading scanned cards

Tags: java, android, linux-kernel, smartcard

I am trying to use a card reader (OmniKey) with Android Box. So far I am able to check the device hooked up into the system. I want to get the scanned cards. I have found some useful post on StackOverflow

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366577/2696230
- [Communicate with smartcard reader through Android USB host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975868/communicate-with-smartcard-reader-through-android-usb-host)

I am able to hookup to the device through Java:

```
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("/dev/bus/usb/001/004");
```

Following other posts that inorder to use the reader, I need to activate using the following command:

```
write(connection, epOut, "62000000000000000000");
```

> returns 36  32  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30
> 30  30  30  30

next, when try to read from the device, the result is -1; and after a few attempts; the device becomes silent (unreponsive) where I had to unplug and plug back.

I was able to pull this line from the android device using command line:

```
<6>[    2.476262] hid-generic 0003:076B:5428.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID OMNIKEY 5427 CK] on usb-ff500000.usb-1.5/input0
```

Is there any way to read the scanned cards?
Am I actually on the correct path? I was expecting to have the scanned IDs straightforwad, but I am now in very deep technical issue. If anyone can clarify that this is the normal behaviour on Android Box?